# How to use callback in jcarousel to place text animations within the slides?

Tags: jquery, animation, jcarousel

I've built a slideshow with jcarousel and I'd like to have text animate in after a slide has transitioned in the slideshow. So the slide comes in first, then the text animates in afterwards.

I've been trying to find out how to use a callback feature so that whenever a slide 'hits' it fires some text animation. However I haven't found anything that works yet.

What I want to do is similar to what is described here: [jQuery cycle for text animation on a slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385651/jquery-cycle-for-text-animation-on-a-slideshow)

I've looked into using the 'ScrollIntoView' plugin but don't think it does what I intend.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with `targetin` and `targetout` event listeners.  Documentation for jcarousel events: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/events.html

You could also try `visiblein` and `visibleout`

Example setup if you have the text element inside each slide:

```
$('.jcarousel')
    .on('jcarousel:targetin', 'li', function() {
        // "this" refers to the item element
        // "carousel" is the jCarousel instance
        var $slide = $(this);
        $slide.removeClass('active-slide');

        //sudo code, but put animations here
        $slide.find('.text-effect-element').animate();
    })
    .on('jcarousel:targetout', 'li', function() {
        // "this" refers to the item element
        // "carousel" is the jCarousel instance
        var $slide = $(this);
        $slide.removeClass('active-slide');

        //sudo code, but put animations here
        $slide.find('.text-effect-element').animate();
    });
```

You could also use css animations dependent on the class of the parent slide.